# Apache CustomLog directive failing - pipe

Tags: mysql, python, apache2

I have the following directive in my apache2_site.conf file:

```
        CustomLog "|/home/me/myjlog.py %h \"%r\"" common
```

which should create a log in my MySQL server. `myjlog.py` starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymysql
import sys

ip=sys.argv[1]
req=sys.argv[2]
...
```

However, for each request to my site, the logging in my database isn't done.

What appears in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is:

```
AH00106: piped log program '/home/me/myjlog.py %h "%r"' failed unexpectedly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alibaba/myjlog.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

It seems that python doesn't recognize the module `pymysql`. However this module is installed for users `me` and `root`...

How may I guarantee access to `pymysql` to `apache2`?

EDIT:
1 - I don't use any virtual environment on this server.
2 - After setting `chmod -R g+rx /home/me/.local` and `chmod -R a+rx /home/me/.local`, I run `sudo -u www-data python3 -m site` and obtained:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/me',
    '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/me/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

But still the `CustomLog` directive can't access `pymysql`.